# SiteCatalyst conversion rate as trendline

Tags: adobe-analytics

I want to analyze data for an account signup process on my web site. I'm using SiteCatalyst for web tracking.

I've set up a Fallout report with the 3 pages that makes up the signup process. In this report I can see how many visitors that I'm losing in every step and a "Total Conversion" and "Total Fallout" at the end.

1. I would like to plot the Total Conversion as a trendline over time. Is that possible?
2. I would also like to plot another version of Conversion, where the rate is the number of visits on the last page of the signup process but divided by the total number of visits to my site.

Thanks
Mike M

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You need to trend a success event or a calculated metric though - so make sure that you've got an event being set or calculated when the conversion occurs.  You can then trend the metric over time.
Tim